# Obtener una variable dependiendo del $_GET

Tags: php

Estoy intentando hacer un script en `PHP`, qué dependiendo del `$_GET` de la URL se muestre una variable u otra.

Aquí les explicaré, imaginen la URL `dominio.com/script.php?var1=`

```
<?php
$resultado1 = "Código UNO"; // Aquí va el resultado en el caso de la url tenga var1<br>
$resultado2 = "Código DOS"; // Aquí va el resultado en el caso de la url tenga var2

if($var_solicitado = htmlspecialchars($_GET["var1"])){
if ($var_solicitado == "RESULTADO1") {
echo $resultado1;
exit();
}
}
if($var_solicitado = htmlspecialchars($_GET["var2"])){
if ($var_solicitado == "RESULTADO2") {
echo $resultado2;
exit();
}
}
?>
```

Entonces sí `dominio.com/script.php?var1=RESULTADO1` se verá `Código UNO`
En cambio si `dominio.com/script.php?var2=RESULTADO2` se verá `Código DOS`

¿es posible?

**Edit:** Este nuevo script sería más o menos como lo tenía pensado usar, para mostrar una imagen o video dependiendo de `$_GET`

```
<?php
if ($tv_solicitado = "CARTOON") {
    $server1 = "cn01";
    $server2 = "cn02";
}
if ($tv_solicitado = "DISNEY") {
    $server1 = "dsn01";
    $server2 = "dsn02";
}
if ($tv_solicitado = "DISNEYXD") {
    $server1 = "dsxd01";
    $server2 = "dsxd02";
}
 
    if($tv_solicitado = htmlspecialchars($_GET["imagen"])){
        echo $server1;
            exit();
    }
    if($tv_solicitado = htmlspecialchars($_GET["video"])){
        echo $server2;
            exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Imagino que recién estas dando tus primeros pasos en programación. Mi consejo... [identá tu código](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentaci%C3%B3n); tu vida y la de los demás va a ser más feliz si lo haces =)

Comment: ¿Por qué dos variables? Creo que sería más sencillo si usas una sola con diferente valor.

Comment: he publicado un edit para explicar más o menos lo que tenía pensado para usar dos variables, gracias por responder

Answer (score 0):

### Edición

Como explicaba en la **Primera respuesta** (ver al final). Cuando mandas datos vía URL, esos datos son convertidos en un array y guardados en la superglobal `$_GET`, la cual **no es otra cosa que un array**.

Todavía en tu pregunta quedan lagunas y no ayudas que bases parte del código en datos ficticios (`var1` y `var2`)  que no tienen nada que ver con lo que luego intentas buscar en `$_GET`. Luego, no se explica de dónde sale `$tve_solicitado` ni qué relación tiene con lo que está llegando en `$_GET`. Si planteas desde el principio el contexto real del código se entendería con mayor claridad y podrás obtener mejores respuestas.

No obstante, en la nueva edición de la pregunta, se puede intuir que estructurar la lógica partiendo de un array simplificaría bastante las cosas (aunque queda la laguna sobre `$tve_solicitado`, la cual no veo claro cómo encaja en todo esto).

El problema en el fondo es que estás planteando la lógica al revés. Vamos a partir del `$_GET`. Por lo que planteas, podŕían estar viajando datos como estos o parecidos en tu `$_GET`:

```
$_GET=array(
                "imagen"=>"CARTOON",  
                "video" =>"DISNEY"
            );
```

Se mandan dos valores, uno asociado a `imagen` y otro asociado a `video`  y partiendo de esos valores se debe obtener el `servidor1` (para `imagen`)  y el `servidor2` (para `video`).

Esto se podría resolver definiendo la lógica en un array y comparando el `$_GET` contra ese array.

Por ejemplo:

```
#Array donde definimos cada contenido asociado
$mValues=
    array(
           "CARTOON"  =>array("server1"=>"cn01",   "server2"=>"cn02"),
           "DISNEY"   =>array("server1"=>"dsn01",  "server2"=>"dsn02"),
           "DISNEYXD" =>array("server1"=>"dsxd01", "server2"=>"dsxd02")
          );
```

Ahora comparamos el contenido del `$_GET` **cualquiera que éste sea**, contra `$mValues`:

```
if (isset($_GET["imagen"]) && array_key_exists($_GET["imagen"],$mValues)){
    echo $mValues[$_GET["imagen"]]["server1"];
}

echo PHP_EOL;

if (isset($_GET["video"]) && array_key_exists($_GET["video"],$mValues)){
    echo $mValues[$_GET["video"]]["server2"];
}
```

**Prueba:**

Supongamos que estés recibiendo esto en el `$_GET`:

```
$_GET=array(
             "imagen"=>"CARTOON",  
             "video" =>"DISNEY"
            );
```

El código anterior te dará los siguientes resultados:

```
cn01    //server1 (imagen)
dsn02   //server2 (video)
```

#### Post-Data

Con esto deberías resolver tu problema. Si no es así, como ya dije, quedan lagunas explicativas en tu planteamiento. Define con claridad el contexto y podremos ayudarte a resolver esto de la forma más simple y coherente posible.

---

### Primera respuesta

Primeramente, al hacer esto:

```
dominio.com/script.php?var1=
```

Lo que haces es asociar a una clave `var1` un valor vacío, lo cual no tiene sentido. El script se ejecuta con esa URL, `$_GET` viene a ser un array como este:

```
$_GET=array('var1'=>'');
```

Si tú quieres ejecutar una determinada acción en base al contenido de la URL puedes hacer algo así, cambiaré el nombre de la clave para que se entienda mejor (`var1, var2, varN` no significan nada realmente para fines de entender con lo que se está trabajando).

Quizá tenga más sentido preparar una URL así:

```
dominio.com/script.php?action=1
```

Aquí, `_GET` será algo así:

```
$_GET=array('action'=>'1');
```

O bien,

```
dominio.com/script.php?action=2
```

En cuyo caso, `_GET` será algo así:

```
$_GET=array('action'=>'2');
```

Ahora obtendrías limpiamente el valor de `action` y, según sea `1` o `2` ejecutarías el bloque de código uno o dos. Quizá un `switch ... case` es más apropiado aquí.

Por ejemplo:

```
#Verificamos que la clave action existe y recuperamos su valor
$mAction=!empty($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : NULL;

switch ($mAction) {
    case 1:
       echo "Poner aquí bloque de código 1";
       break;
    case 2:
       echo "Poner aquí bloque de código 2";
       break;
    default:
       echo "Aquí lo que haya que hacer cuando no sea ni 1 ni 2";
}
```

Comment: Es genial y te lo agradezco, algo nuevo aprendido!

Comment: @Daniel revisa la respuesta editada. Si esto no resuelve tu problema explica con más claridad el contexto: lo que recibes **realmente** en el `$_GET`, compartiendo si es posible el resultado de un `var_dump($_GET);` y de dónde sale `$tve_solicitado` y qué relación tiene con el resto del código.